# How to query openLDAP servers cert?

Tags: ldap, certificates, sles, openldap

From the "service sssd status" we can see:

> Could not start TLS encryption. TLS: hostname does not match CN in
>   peer certificate

But how could we query the cert to know, that it is really some cert-related issue?

The configs under /etc looks like the same for good and bad servers (bad servers having the mentioned error message for CN).

The "installcert" could not be found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20259257

Using port 389.

Answer (score 0):

start a tcpdump and try to log in with a user:

```
tcpdump -n -i any -s 0 -A port 389 -w out.pcap
```

Then open with wireshark and check for the line "Certificate" and expand the menus until you see the first "*common-name"